Where is iptables configuration persisted?
Where is iptables configuration persisted?  Researching produced no results:
/etc/iptables - no such file or directory
/etc/sysconfig - no such file or directory
/etc/init.d/iptables - no such file or directory
/etc/network/if-up.d/ contains ethtool only
/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ contains ethtool only

Any other places? Running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Your ideas are very appreciated.

Ubuntu 24.04 does not have persistent iptables rules by default. If you want to persist your iptables configuration after a reboot, you will need to install and configure the iptables-persistent package manually or use, e.g., UFW, FirewallD, or nftables for the job.

I have saved iptables rules on this VPS machine myself. They are in effect. Wondering where they are saved, so that I could reset them in rescue mode.

How have you saved them?

/sbin/iptables-save

iptables-save prints the rules to stdout. So, they will be saved wherever you redirected stdout to. Nobody except you knows where that is, so this question is not answerable on Stack Exchange.

That is why the package iptables-persistent exist. You can do a save of running configuration of iptables with iptables-save > saved_file. And you can restore content with iptables-restore < saved_file.

Thank you very very much! Sorted. Happy upcoming holidays everyone
